# Making a es6 variable global in a class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

What I'm trying to do is make a variable which I can use across different functions in the class. But for some reason whenever I write `let variable` above the constructor I get `'Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.`

Tried it with a var and I pretty much get the same result

```js
class ClassName {

  let variable;

  constructor() {
    variable = 1;  
  }
  
  function() {
    console.log(variable + 1);  
  }
  
}
```

Comment: See [Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) on MDN.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should access the variable as a property of `this`:

```js
class ClassName {
  constructor() {
    this.variable = 1;  
  }
  someOtherFunction() {
    console.log(this.variable + 1); // 2
  }
}

new ClassName().someOtherFunction();
```